# Creating array clusters in numpy dynamically

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I am grouping items and make tests on these groups. I use the following code segment to group 10 items into 3 groups.

```
# grouping into 3 clusters and getting the distribution of the elements

node_cluster_labels = sm.cluster(n_clusters=3)
data_cluster_labels =node_cluster_labels[bmus]

print(data_cluster_labels)
```

This following output specifies the first element is in cluster 2 and second element is in cluster 0 and so on..

output: `array([2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0], dtype=int32)`

```
# Formatting clusters to use them for later tests

count = 0;
[inputsSize,y] = myarray.shape

cm = ['cluster 0: ']
cm1 = ['cluster 1: ']
cm2 = ['cluster 2: ']

while(count < inputsSize):
   b = data_cluster_labels[count]
   if (b==0):
       cm.append(arr[count,:])
   elif (b==1): 
       cm1.append(arr[count,:])
   else:
       cm2.append(arr[count,:])

   count += 1
```

Output:

```
     ['cluster 0: ', array([0, 0, 0, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 1]), array([0, 0, 1, 1, 0]), array([0, 1, 0, 1, 0]), array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1])]

     ['cluster 1: ', array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1]), array([0, 0, 1, 0, 0]), array([1, 0, 1, 0, 1])]

     ['cluster 2: ', array([1, 1, 0, 0, 1]), array([1, 1, 1, 0, 1])]
```

My question is: If the number of clusters is variable and context-dependent (i.e., 4 clusters, 10 clusters, 90 clusters, and so on), how can I generate them better than the above code?

Comment: You mean the number of clusters is always equal to the unique items in `data_cluster_labels`?

Comment: No, I mean that clusters are created dynamically while execution time based on the number of clusters which is generated through a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a Vectorized solution that uses the number of unique items within `cluster_labels` to clusters your array.

```
def clustering(array, cluster_labels):
    data_cluster_labels = cluster_labels
    u = np.unique(data_cluster_labels)
    x, y = np.where(u[:, None] == data_cluster_labels)
    changin_indices = np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0] + 1
    clusters = np.split(y, changin_indices)
    return [array[indices] for indices in clusters]
```

Demo:

```
In [40]: data_cluster_labels = np.array([2, 0, 1, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])

In [41]: arr = np.random.randint(0, 3, (10, 5))

In [42]: arr
Out[42]: 
array([[1, 0, 1, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
       [2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
       [1, 1, 2, 2, 1],
       [2, 2, 0, 1, 1],
       [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
       [1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]])

In [43]: u = np.unique(data_cluster_labels)

In [44]: x, y = np.where(u[:, None] == data_cluster_labels)

In [45]: x
Out[45]: array([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2])

In [46]: y
Out[46]: array([1, 3, 6, 7, 9, 2, 5, 8, 0, 4])

In [47]: changin_indices = np.where(np.diff(x) != 0)[0] + 1

In [48]: changin_indices
Out[48]: array([5, 8])

In [50]: clusters = np.split(y, changin_indices)

In [51]: [arr[indices] for indices in clusters]
Out[51]: 
[array([[2, 2, 0, 0, 2],
        [0, 1, 2, 2, 2],
        [0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
        [1, 2, 0, 1, 0],
        [1, 1, 1, 1, 2]]), array([[2, 1, 1, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 0, 1, 1],
        [0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]), array([[1, 0, 1, 2, 1],
        [1, 1, 2, 2, 1]])]
```

Comment: Great job! Thanks @Kasramvd